# Yii framework, Login , SQL injection

Tags: sql, authentication, yii, code-injection

Recently I receive a email, claiming that he can change my admin password by sql injection.
Here is my code. It is developed using Yii php framework. Can anyone see the flaws?

```
    public function actionLogin()
{

    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Comment: Changing password may be done via "forgot password" or similar.

Comment: You will need to post your LoginForm and probably your UserIdentity models before we can see the parts that could be attacked

Comment: Did this person actually change anything?  Could just be somebody trying to scare you.  If it's someone you know, then ask them to clarify what they're saying (for example, what page do they think is vulnerable, etc).  Other than that, we'll need to see more of the login code than just the action.

Comment: I later found there is a flaw in my keyword search action. I forgot to escape the keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every where you are creating sql queries, you must  bind all external variable with sql variables, It will remove sql injection possibility.

Comment: Yii does this by default for all queries, unless he's doing some manual ActiveRecord internals.